# How should I remind my teacher how to spell my name correctly?

Tags: email, letter

I would like to remind a teacher of mine, how to spell my name, Mackenzie. I do not want to be rude or demanding with this, only kindly state my concern. She spells it McKenzie, which I understand, but I have been getting frustrated lately, since this is not how MY name is spelled. Could someone please help he come up with an email to send to her about this issue?

Thank you

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "what to write" isn't on topic here, however you might find some good advice over on [Interpersonal Skills SE](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @motosubatsu♦ I am sorry that you feel that this is off topic, but I am asking a reasonable question and in no place in the question did i state "what to write." If you could please open the question back up, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Jellybean! I'm a mod from Interpersonal Skills, and while 'what to write' isn't on topic on our site either (the site is about behaviors you can use to interact well with others), it might still be of help. For your question to work on IPS, it would need some more details/explanation: Take a look at our [good question guidelines](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3224/1599), specifically points 2, 3 and 4. If you could let us know what you've already tried or what you think you can't try because it would be rude/demanding, we might be able to take your question and help :)

Comment: Look, I'm just asking for advice for sending an email to my teacher clarifying the spelling of my name. It's really nothing that I need to be reported over. I'm not asking for much.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! I'm sorry that your first experience here has been a seemingly negative one. I'd like to reassure you that you're not in any trouble; a single closed question doesn't count against you. I do have to ask, though: you've already marked Spencer Barnes' answer as having helped you, so is there any particular reason you *need* the question to be re-opened again?

Comment: I just would like to have more than 1 choice for ideas for sending an email.I do not NEED another choice, but it would just be nice.

Comment: I don't understand why my question got closed. I'm pretty sure I didn't do anything that would make this happen. Could someone please let me know why this happened?

Answer (score 1):

It's your name (therefore your spelling), and it's not an unreasonable or difficult request, so I don't see that anyone can really complain no matter how you ask. That said, politeness never hurt anybody; my go-to would be something along the lines of:-

> Afternoon Ms [Surname],
> I've noticed a couple of times that you changed my name spelling on zoom. No offense, but would you mind refraining from this please? My name really is spelt Mackenzie.
> Many Thanks,

...unless you feel it would need some more force or detail? As I said it's not a difficult or unreasonable thing you're asking, and it's perfectly natural for you to be concerned as your name is pretty much your most defining personal detail, so the teacher isn't likely to refuse or be offended.